At least four numbers using the two digits in those numbers only once
Can you give me at least four 2 digit integer numbers formed by using the two individual digits in that number exactly once and the following math operators only
Add +, Subtract -, multiply *,divide /, ^ to the power, factorial !, double factorial !!, paranthesis ( )  and _/ which is square root. In your equation the two digits must show up only once. No additional digits in any form.
Example only. Not a hint. May not be an answer
Number  AB = A! / B  Equation must be correct
A and B are separate integers
Please try it without programming

Here are four which also keep the order of the two digits:

 $3!\times 6=36$


 $(2\times\sqrt 4)!=24$


 $1\times 5!! = 15$


 $(4!!)!!/8 = 48$


Did you get it by trial and error or you used some method/

@RogerA mostly trial-and-error and a bias towards factorials because +,-,x,/ on their own clearly cannot work.

Some more

 48 can be made with a lot of single numbers:
$48=6!! = (3!)!! = (\sqrt 9!)!!$
 using that we can also make:
$46 = 6!! - \sqrt 4$
$39 = (3!)!! - 9$


You can also make 96 with that.

Some more, not keeping the  digit order

 $(2+\sqrt 4)!=24$


 $((4!!)/2)! = 24$


 $5^2 = 25$


 $(8-\sqrt 4)!!=48$


 $(\sqrt 4)^6 = 64$


Even more

$5+(3!)!!=53$


$\left(\dots\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt4}}\right)+(\sqrt9!)!!=49$


$\binom82=28$


$9-(3!)!!=-39$


$\sqrt4-6!!=-46$

